# What is the point of including header files in a makefile?

Tags: makefile, header

My C++ instructor told us to include headers in the makefiles as a dependency. But I don't see the purpose of this when the respective source file, say `example.cpp` already has a `#include "example.h"`. So it seems to me including them or not doesn't change the compilation Could someone explain the purpose of their inclusion in a `makefile`?

The one thing that did come across my mind that makes it useful to have as a dependency has to do with a process like:

(1) execute `make all` using a `makefile` that doesn't include the headers as dependencies in the `makefile`

(2) modify some header file and no other files.

(3) run `make all` again without doing a `make clean`.

I think this procedure would lead to `nothing to be done by make` because the `makefile` directives are not picking up on the changes in the header file?

Comment: I hope you will enjoy reading *[Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/)*

Answer (score 1):

The point of 'make' is to automatically handle dependencies.  So you'd want to tell it about dependencies.  Otherwise, as you observe, it cannot rebuild that which needs rebuilding,

Comment: Ah I wasn't sure if I was correct. But doesn't the dependencies in the `makefile` get pretty massive if you have a bunch of `#include "header.h"` in the source file, meaning that you'd have to add all the header files as a dependency in the `makefile` when building that source file's object file?

Comment: I wouldn't bother with any header files that were not directly part of your project.  How many project files do you have?   You can take the lazy way out and arrange that each object file depends on all .h files (so any .h file change will cause total recompile).  It's been a while since I needed to write a makefile so I forget the exact syntax,

Comment: I'm not doing any large projects atm. I was just wondering out of curiosity because in some project's codes that I've observed, they have a massive amount of headers for user defined header files. It would be very tedious to have to type all those out as a dependency if you're manually creating a `makefile`. I guess this is probably one of the reason why people use software like `cmake` for auto-generating make files?

Comment: I usually add my .cpp/.hpp files in pairs. And each time I do I make sure to add both of them to the Makefile at once.  Like the other use said, tracking .h files that are not part of your project doesn't make much sense.  If you need to upgrade your OS, you can always `make clean` `make` afterwards.